# How to use immersive reader on Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud

I am following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/immersive-reader/how-to-create-immersive-reader) and run the function create-immersiveReaderResource provided by Azure docs and get an error.

```
  -SubscriptionName '<SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>' `
>>   -ResourceName '<RESOURCE_NAME>' `
>>   -ResourceSubdomain '<RESOURCE_SUBDOMAIN>' `
>>   -ResourceSKU '<RESOURCE_SKU>' `
>>   -ResourceLocation '<RESOURCE_LOCATION>' `
>>   -ResourceGroupName '<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>' `
>>   -ResourceGroupLocation '<RESOURCE_GROUP_LOCATION>' `
>>   -AADAppDisplayName '<AAD_APP_DISPLAY_NAME>' `
>>   -AADAppIdentifierUri '<AAD_APP_IDENTIFIER_URI>' `
>>   -AADAppClientSecret '<AAD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET>'
-SubscriptionName: The term '-SubscriptionName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PS /home/xxxx>-AADAppClientSecretExpiration '<AAD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET_EXPIRATION>'
-AADAppClientSecretExpiration: The term '-AADAppClientSecretExpiration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I dont know why I am always getting this error. For subscriptionName I filled it with string values for ex : azuretest and clientsecretexpiration with format provided by microsoft docs ex:2020-12-31 . Any suggestions? I am using MacBook Pro and Powershell in Azure.

Comment: You need to copy the function you have linked to on top of your script. Then **call** it by using its name followed by all the parameters. Now you just sum up the parameters and leave out the function itsef **AND** the function name. The error message is quite clear as is the example in the link..

Comment: Have you define the right function? Could you please provide your script?

Comment: Thanks the problem solved because iam define a wrong function

Comment: Since the issue has been resolved by yourself, could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, copy and paste the PowerShell function snippet in step 2 on the page you linked into your terminal, then hit Enter. That will create the `Create-ImmersiveReaderResource` function. Then you need to then run the function.

The example provided on the page requires some editing. Below is an example snippet that would work. Note that I have included spaces between the parameters, removed extra spaces at the end of parameters, and removed the backticks, i.e '`'.

Also remember to change the actual values within the quotes.

```
Create-ImmersiveReaderResource -SubscriptionName 'My Subscription Name' -ResourceName 'myResourceName' -ResourceSubdomain 'myResource-immersive' -ResourceSKU 'S0' -ResourceLocation 'eastus' -ResourceGroupName 'myResourceGroupName' -ResourceGroupLocation 'eastus' -AADAppDisplayName 'myAADDisplayName' -AADAppIdentifierUri 'http://myresource' -AADAppClientSecret "My5uperSecretClientSecret!" -AADAppClientSecretExpiration '2020-12-31'
```

If you don't want to do it all in one go, you can always run the `Create-ImmersiveReaderResource` function only, and then it will drop-down to a prompt where you can type in your desired values one after another.

There is also a video that demonstrates the process [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/immersive-reader-sdk-part2-aad-authentication-configuration/).